# Mavericks and pro tools 9

Tags: pro-tools-9

Has anyone found a work around  for using Pro-tools-9 with Maverick? If not what is the best way to go back to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Pro Tools 9 to 2009 imac, 2010 MacBook Pro, 2008 MacPro and latest iMac. All running with Mavericks. Running nicely with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Macworld wrote an excellent article about how to revert to an older OS.

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/downgrade-mavericks-mountain-lion-3494785/

For as long as you stick with PT 9.05 try and keep the same OS, which in this case should ideally be 10.7.x (Lion)

http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/compatibility/en352429?popup=true

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks and 9 run fine. Just be sure to back  up and update your audio drivers if they're from avid.